# 403 Forbidden accessing OSHA violations (X-API-KEY in header)

Tags: api, labor

X-API-KEY with key value in header of a request to https://data.dol.gov/get/violation, but still receiving 403 Forbidden "Invalid API Key" error. Is anything missing/incorrect in this request? Any help is greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, how?